# Can someone explain the verb vorstellen to me? When does it come with dative and other times with akkusativ?

Tags: verb, grammatical-case, question

> Ich stelle euch der deutsche Gerichte vor.

Euch here is dativ or akkusativ?

Is there any list for the verb *vorstellen* and the grammatical case with ever meaning?

Answer (score 2):

> Ich stelle euch <s>der</s> deutsche **G**erichte vor: *(a list of dishes follows)*

The verb *vorstellen* takes a mandatory accusative object (from the example: *deutsche Gerichte*) which is the thing presented, and an optional dative object, which is the intended audience (from the example: *euch*).

If you don't need the thing presented, you have to drop in an *es*, because the accusative object is mandatory:

> Ich stelle **es** mir vor.

Instead of the accusative object, an object clause may be used:

> Ich stelle mir vor, dass ich schon dort bin.

And of course, such an object clause may be replaced by an infinitive clause.

> Ich stelle mir vor, schon dort zu sein.

Comment: thanks but another off topic qestion, why deutsche gerichte is the accusative ! not euch ? 
how do i differntiate between which of them is dative and which is accusative

Comment: *Euch* in fact can be both accusative and dative. But *deutsche Gerichte* can't, it's either nominative or accusative. Dative would be *deutschen Gerichte**n***. But yes, there are sentences where it isn't clear from grammar alone. You have to guess the correct meaning then.